# EditText loses focus inside ListView

Tags: android, listview, focus, android-edittext

When typing in an Edit Text in my ListView, focus is constantly lost and regained, causes onFocusChangeListeners to go nuts, and for my list item to sink beneath the soft keyboard.

I had read through all the answers saying I should use "adjustPan" or "adjustResize" or "beforeDescendants" or "afterDecendants" fixes that seemed to work for a lot of people, but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

In your code/java classes, change any reference of ListView to AbsListView (.

In your xml, change any ListView that's causing problems into a GridView, with android:numColumns=1

All problems were solved with this fix.

GridView doesn't have the same divider attributes that ListViews do, so you may manually need to add a divider to your list item's view.